# aws Decrypted Variables Error Message: parameter does not exist: JWT_SECRET

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, kubectl, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am new to aws I was trying to create a pipeline. But it turns this error once it builds

```
[Container] 2020/05/23 04:32:56 Phase context status code: Decrypted Variables Error Message: parameter does not exist: JWT_SECRET
```

Even though the token was stored by running this command

```sh
s ssm put-parameter --name JWT_SECRET --value "myjwtsecret" --type  SecureString
```

I tried to fix that by adding this line `buildspec.yml` post build commands. but still does not fix the problem

```sh
- kubectl set env deployment/simple-jwt-api JWT_SECRET=$JWT_SECRET
```

My `buildspec.yml` contain this added line to configure the pass of my jwt secret to the app

```
env:
  parameter-store:         
    JWT_SECRET: JWT_SECRET
```

> Check my [github repos](https://github.com/DinaTaklit/Deploy-Flask-App-to-Kubernetes-Using-EKS) for more details about the code

Also once I run this under cmd to test the api endpoints `kubectl get services simple-jwt-api -o wide` I have got this error

```
Error from server (NotFound): services "simple-jwt-api" not found
```

Well it is obvious since the pipeline failed to build. Please how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the parameter store variable in same region as CodBuild project?

Comment: I spend a lot of hours discovering that I created a stack in diff regions than the cluster and that is why I got this error that I managed manually and later the cluster with the given name does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I go this error while I have created my stack in different region than the cluster. So whenever it search for the variable it does not find it. So, be carful to point to the same region in every creation action :).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to add a region tag when declaring the env variables.

`aws ssm put-parameter --name JWT_SECRET --value "myjwtsecret" --type  SecureString --region <your-cluster-region>`

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this same issue,

> Changing the **kubectl version** in the **buildspec.yml** file worked for me

```
- curl -LO https://dl.k8s.io/release/v<YOUR_KUBERNETES_VERSION>/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
# Download the kubectl checksum file
- curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/v<YOUR_KUBERNETES_VERSION>/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl.sha256"
```

Note that the <**YOUR_KUBERNETES_VERSION**> must be the same with what you have on your created cluster dashboard.